# connect 2 PC's together via the PSTN using dial up modems

Tags: remote-desktop, dial-up

I want to connect 2 PC's together via the PSTN using dial up modems and run remote desktop. Both machines have Windows 8. Both have modems. I know there are speed issues and that there are more elegant and better ways of doing it. The machines are remote from each other and without internet access by any means.

I assume I ought to be able to get a speed of about 24KB/s over this sort of link up if achieved. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're dreaming. 6.835KB/s is the absolute theoretical limit (do the math). Realistically, you might get 4.1KB/s.

Comment: @DaviidSchwartz - ignoring compression, the theoretical limit is less, as in order to get > 33.6k you need an ISDN modem on the other side, so maximum is 4.2Kb / second ignoring packet overhead.  Of-course this ignores compression, and with compression and a reduced color palet I think you would get more then 24KB / sec

Answer (score -1):

I never worked on windows 8. I jumped up from 7 to 10. So I just give you a hint and rest you can google how to do that.
1st of all you need microsoft loopback adapter installed on the remote computer to which you want to dial. It helps in giving an IP address to the dialup connection.
Then you need to configure dial-in connection to the remote computer. 
So when you will make a dialup connection to the remote computer, the modems will get connected with each other and an IP address will be assigned to both computers. The IP address configured on the loopback adapter on remote computer be used to get your vnc work.
Best of luck

Comment: And remember it cannot be 24KB/s rather it will be 24Kb/s or max upto 44kbps but it all depends upon line conditions and the quality of networks. U may face a problem of connection coz now the calls are IP based at the Core Network level so many voice compression codecs are used at core level. If it is so your dialup system may not work or both the numbers should be in fax enabled mode by the telephone exchanges.

Comment: what you said about installing the loopback adaptor does not make sense.  Any computer with a network stack (including all versions of Windows) will have a loopback adaptor installed.   What would be needed would be needed is some kind of PPP server and client, with the PPP server providing an IP address to the client.